# how to create a new collection automatically in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

my main issue is how do this architecture - if a user creates a new list in database and there is a separate collections for storing lists ,then i should redirect him when he want to access a specific list where he can store his contacts by assigning him some collection in database, now the problem comes for me, if there are 'n' lists of a specific user for saving his contacts by categorizing in to lists based on his need , then how should i implement this architecture any suggestions ? or there's a mistake with what i have done so far ? any corrections ?

i am using mongodb,nodejs with express framework

What i have so far done is manually i was able to create a new list and allocate a collection for it so that user can add his contacts in that list.
But creating collections manually for each and every list is not possible so i am searching for a method where we can automatically create a new collection on demand.

Is there any method to create n collection or n sub collections in mongodb ?

This is my js file for adding contacts in a collection , where i have stored those contacts in two separate list with separate collection for each list.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var $ = require("jquery");
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

/* GET New User page. in list 1 */
router.get('/mylist', function(req, res) {
    res.render('mylist', { title: 'Go To My-List' });
});


router.post('/delcontact', function(req, res){
    console.log('Using delcontact');

    var db = req.db;
    var collection  = db.get('golists');

    console.log('Got this : ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));
    var delcontact = req.body;
    var emails = Object.keys(delcontact).map(function(k) { return delcontact[k] });
    for(var z=0; z<emails.length; z++){

      //console.log('email: \n' + emails[z]);
      collection.remove({email: emails[z]},  
        function(err, doc, z) { 
          if (err)
            res.send('delete unsuccessfull');
          else {
            console.log('Selected contacts deleted');
          }
      });

    res.send({redirect: '/userlist2'});
    var collection = db.get('golists');

  };
});


/* POST to Add User Service */
router.post('/addusers', function(req, res) {

    // Set our internal DB variable
    var db = req.db;

    // Get our form values. These rely on the "name" attributes
    var firstName = req.body.firstname;
    var lastName = req.body.lastname
    var userEmail = req.body.useremail;

    // Set our collection
    var collection = db.get('golists');



        // Submit to the DB
    collection.insert({
        "firstname" : firstName,
        "lastname"  : lastName,
        "email" : userEmail
    }, function (err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            // If it failed, return error
            res.send("There was a problem adding the information to the database.");
        }
        else {
            // If it worked, set the header so the address bar doesn't still say /adduser
            res.location("mailinglist");
            // And forward to success page
            res.redirect("mailinglist");
        }
    });
});


/* GET Userlist page. */
router.get('/mailinglist', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('golists');
    collection.find({},{},function(e,docs){
        res.render('userlist2', {
            "userlist2" : docs
        });
    });
});


/* this is for list 2 */

router.get('/mylist2', function(req, res) {
    res.render('mylist2', { title: 'Go To My-List' });
});

router.post('/addusers2', function(req,res){

   //Set our internal DB variable
    var db = req.db;

    // Get our form values. These rely on the "name" attributes
    var firstName = req.body.firstname;
    var lastName = req.body.lastname
    var userEmail = req.body.useremail;

    // Set our collection
    var collection = db.get('golists2');





    // Submit to the DB
    collection.insert({
        "firstname" : firstName,
        "lastname"  : lastName,
        "email" : userEmail
    }, function (err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            // If it failed, return error
            res.send("There was a problem adding the information to the database.");
        }
        else {
            // If it worked, set the header so the address bar doesn't still say /adduser
            res.location("mailinglist2");
            // And forward to success page
            res.redirect("mailinglist2");
        }
    });
});

/* GET Userlist page. */
router.get('/mailinglist2', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('golists2');
    collection.find({},{},function(e,docs){
        res.render('mailinglist2', {
            "mailinglist2" : docs
        });
    });
});

router.post('/delcontact2', function(req, res){
    console.log('Using delcontact');

    var db = req.db;
    var collection  = db.get('golists2');

    console.log('Got this : ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));
    var delcontact = req.body;
    var emails = Object.keys(delcontact).map(function(k) { return delcontact[k] });
    for(var z=0; z<emails.length; z++){

      //console.log('email: \n' + emails[z]);
      collection.remove({email: emails[z]},  
        function(err, doc, z) { 
          if (err)
            res.send('delete unsuccessfull');
          else {
            console.log('Selected contacts deleted');
          }
      });

    res.send({redirect: '/mailinglist2'});
    var collection = db.get('golists2');

  };
});
```

this is my file for creating new lists in some collection

```
router.get('/newlist',function(req,res){
    res.render("newlist" ,{titile:'Add new list'}) ;
});

router.post('/addlist',function(req,res){

    var db= req.db;

    var listname=req.body.listname;

    var collection=db.get("lists");

    collection.insert({
        "listname":listname
    }, function (err,doc) {
        if(err) {
            res.send("There was a problem adding new list to database");
        }

        else {
            res.location('lou');
            res.redirect('lou');
        }   
    });
});

router.get('/lou',function(req,res){
    var db=req.db;
    var collection=db.get("lists");
    collection.find({},{},function(e,docs){
        res.render('lou', {
            "lou" : docs
        });
    });
});


router.get('/drop', function(req, res) {
    res.render('drop', { title: 'Go To My-List' });
});
```

my jade file for this is

```
body


    nav.navbar.navbar-default
      .container-fluid

        ul.nav.navbar-nav
              li.active
                a(href='/mailinglist')     
                  | List 1 
                  span.sr-only (current)
              |         
              li
                a(href='/mailinglist2') 
                  | List 2
 tbody
  ul

      p Import Contact From Your DB
      a(href='/upload2') Go 
      table.table#stable
        caption User Contact Details 
        |         
        thread
          tr 
            th #
            |             
            th FirstName
            |             
            th LastName
            |              
            th Email ID
            |         

        each user, i in userlist2
            tr(id=i)
              td 
                input.contactID(type='checkbox')
              td
                | #{user.firstname} 
              td
                | #{user.lastname}  
              td(id='email'+i)
                | #{user.email}




      button.btn.btn-danger#delete-button Delete Selected Contacts
```

Comment: Why don't you put all your lists in one collection? MongoDB is designed to have many documents in one collection and not to have many collections with one document.

Comment: @ThomasBormans suppose there are 3 lists ,If i have only one collection then a user adds contacts in one of the list,then the contacts added will be show in all 3 lists or else it will be show in only one list ? i having a little bit confusion.

Comment: what i have done is i allocated one collection for saving the lists in database and another collection for saving the contacts of users in a specified list. Manually i did it for 3 lists. What makes me go weird is, how i should allocate a collection for making new lists in lists and then adding contacts to the specified list. I am new to this Mongodb and Nodejs finding very difficult to get what i want.can u suggest me the best method i should do for this ?

Comment: Please edit your question with your problem and give more (and specific) examples of the data you are storing and what you want to achieve. It will make it a lot easier for everyone.

Comment: can u get what i am trying to do ? @ThomasBormans

Comment: I am terribly sorry but no... You're creating routes, functions, ... but your data storage schema('s) aren't correct. So far a user can create several lists and can link several contacts so each list. One contact can be linked to one or more lists. This however doesn't explain the need for multiple collections, let alone one collection for each user.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this doesn't sound like a good idea. It would be much better when you have one collection for all lists of all users. The problem with having too many collections is that MongoDB doesn't offer any tools for selecting data from more than one collection at a time. So when you want to query data from multiple collections, you will have to perform multiple queries, which is very unperformant.

However, when you are determined to cling to this architecture, MongoDB automatically creates a collection when you insert data into a collection-name it doesn't know.

Comment: Is a $lookup not similar to a join? https://farenda.com/mongodb/mongodb-join-collections/

Comment: @MrMesees It didn't in 2015. But even today $lookup is only of limited use because it does not work on sharded collections.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks