# How to sort data in mongodb - best practice

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm rather new to working with MongoDB.
In my application, the user can create to-do-lists. I save the data of these to-do-lists to my database using node.js with express framework and mongoose (with a ReactJS front-end), however, the user is supposed to be able to create several to-do-lists and I'm not sure about how to best sort the data of these lists so I can always access the correct data in my corresponding to-do-list.

Let's say I have this schema:

```
var TodoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    task: String,
    prio: String,
    updated_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Todo", TodoSchema);
```

for my database called `tododb`.
I was first planning on creating a new collection for each new list, but in this question ( [how to create a new collection automatically in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27875400/how-to-create-a-new-collection-automatically-in-mongodb) ) it says that it would be much better to create one collection for all lists, however, I'm not sure about how you would filter out the correct data in this case.

I imagine that I'm not the first person to encounter this problem, so how is it done usually? What other options do I have besides collections? And how would I access exactly the data that I need?

Edit: I was also thinking about just adding an element called "name" or something similar, where the user could enter a name for the list, and when fetching the data I would iterate over all data and filter out the once whose name matches, however, that seems terribly inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd model a todo list like the following:

```
{
     "_id": "id of the todo list",
     "name": "name of the todo list (e.g. daily tasks)",
     "tasks" : [
         {"name": "drink coffee", priority: 1,  updated: "sometime" },
         {"name": "write code", priority: 2,  updated: "sometime" },
         {"name": "drink tea", priority: 3,  updated: "sometime" }
     ]
}
```

and then put them all in the same collection, if you need to split by user, just add a `userId` field to the todo list document.

Comment: thank you, I'll try that! one more question (I hope it's not too off-topic but I feel like it's so "small" that I don't want to ask a separate question): If added let's say 5 tasks for the to-do-list and wanted to post them on submit TOGETHER (and not enter task->submit->task is added to database->enter next task -...), how would I do that?

Comment: You can use the `$push` operator with an `$each`, so all 5 will get pushed in to the array together.

Comment: No problem, anytime